# generating standard normals using a double exponential

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I'm trying to write a code for generating standard normals using a double exponential distribution. In other words,

`x` is a double exponential that I've already coded correctly here:

```
double.exponential.rv<-function(i)
{
  u<-runif(1)
  x<--log(1-u)
  v<-runif(1)
  if (v<.5) x<-(-x)
  return(x)
}
```

where `i=1`

`y` is a normal distribution from `0` to `(sqrt(exp(1)/(2*pi)))*exp(-abs(x)))`

so far my code is this:

```
std.normal.rv<-function(i)
{
  while(1)
  {
    x<-double.exponential.rv(1)
    y<-runif(1)*(sqrt(exp(1)/(2*pi)))*exp(-abs(x))
    if (y<=(sqrt(exp(1)/(2*pi)))*exp(-abs(x))) return(x)
  }  
  hist(x,nclass=100,freq=FALSE)
}
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong but I receive the Error:no function to return from, jumping to top level

And it doesn't plot.  Any suggestions to fix my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should throw in some English explanation? It appears you are making a histogram with one point, and are also giving `lines` one point as well,

Comment: my mistake- the lines line was a mistake